# How to fade in and fade out back and forth in android studio without button

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a simple app in which there is an image that fades out and then another image fades in but now I have to just create that back and forth every time after the second image fades in I want to click that image back to first and the back and forth.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void fade(View view){

        ImageView homer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homer);
        ImageView bart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bart);

        homer.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        bart.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

    }
```

Comment: `without button` and then you say `I want to click` , what exactly do you want?

Comment: It's like a button too has onclick property and Imageview too so by click I mean when I tap on the image it should fade out and another image should fade in and then when I again tap on the image the other image should fade out and the first image should fade in!

Comment: write a condition to check alpha in fade() and write your code accordingly

Comment: Can you help me with code beginner here!

Comment: For sure I will

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ImageView homer;
    ImageView bart;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         homer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
         bart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        homer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                homer.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
                bart.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

            }
        });
        bart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                homer.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
                bart.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It isn't working, I don't know why I mean app just launches successfully but as previously it used to fade out and another image used to fade in that also stopped. I think we just have to create another method to do the same for the images just changing the alpha and then assign that method to the image.

Comment: @Nikunj Surya In my case it is working don't know why

Comment: @Nikunj Surya Do you change the id( R.id.homer , R.id.bart) to your imageview  in the above code , I used my ids ,

Comment: Yes, I changed the ids. I even changed the method name to onclick!

Comment: @Nikunj Surya `I even changed the method name to onclick!` , which method name , in my answer I dont use your method

Comment: I mean in the image view attributes the onclick property I set it to onClick.